# Should I use NSNumber instead of basic C number types?

Tags: objective-c, c, foundation

What is the benefit of using ***NSNumber*** from Foundation Framework instead of basic C types (int, float, double)?

Using NSNumber:

```
NSNumber *intNumber;
NSInteger myInt;
intNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: 100];
myInt = [intNumber integerValue];
```

Using pure C:

```
int intNumber;
intNumber = 100;
```

Seems a lot easier and economic to use C.

I know NSNumber is an object (or class?) type, but why would I use them instead simple C variables? When should I use them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The purpose of `NSNumber` is simply to box primitive types in objects (pointer types), so you can use them in situations that require pointer-type values to work.

One common example: you have to use `NSNumber` if you want to persist numeric values in Core Data entities.

You can and should use primitives for calculations (unless with decimals, in which case you use `NSDecimal` or `NSDecimalNumber`).

Comment: +1 Also Foundation's collection classes only accept objects, not primitives.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to pass a number as an object, use `NSNumber`.

If you need to make arithmetic operations, you can use `int` and `double`. If you don't want to bother with 32/64 bit issues, you can use `NSInteger` and `CGFloat`.

Answer (score 0):

Because with dealing with passing of parameters with certain objects, using a basic data type will not work. Also, the NSNumber class gives you options for converting values into other datatypes quickly.